# Stack view bug or did I miss something?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, layer

Written a sample app here to illustrate some animation behaviour that doesn't seem quite right? I create a stack view in the lower half of the screen, add a button to it, animate it moving it up the screen {it moves} including the button, but the action attached to the button remains in the lower half?

Indeed if I look at the debugger on Xcode, it hasn't moved at all.

There is some action I missed here? yes?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var selectSV: UIStackView!
var goNorth:CABasicAnimation!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    selectSV = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 256, y: 696, width: 256, height: 196))
    selectSV!.axis = .Vertical
    selectSV!.spacing = 4.0
    selectSV!.alignment = .Center
    selectSV!.distribution = .FillEqually

    let zeroRect = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 0,height: 0)
    let newB = UIButton(frame: zeroRect)
    newB.setTitle("Blah", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    newB.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Palatino", size: 24)
    newB.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 128, height: 32)
    newB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.blahblah(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    newB.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    self.selectSV.addArrangedSubview(newB)
    self.view.addSubview(selectSV)
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.moveSV), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func blahblah(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("You hit me!")
}

func moveSV() {
    self.animateNorth()
    self.selectSV.layer.addAnimation(self.goNorth, forKey: nil)
}

func animateNorth() {
    goNorth = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
    goNorth.fromValue = 792
    goNorth.toValue = 288
    goNorth.duration = 4.0
    goNorth.delegate = self
    goNorth.setValue("window", forKey:"goNorth")
    goNorth.removedOnCompletion = false
    goNorth.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are animating the backing layer of your stackview and not the frame of the stackview itself. To animate the stackview you could use  the  `UIView` method `animateWithDuration:animations:` and animate the `frame` property of the stackview. To see better what happens now, you could enable `selectSV.clipsToBounds = true` to your stackview. That way the `layer` of the stackview is clipped when it gets out of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jelly!

Commented out this ...

```
 self.animateNorth()
 self.selectSV.layer.addAnimation(self.goNorth, forKey: nil)
```

and replaced it with this works perfectly!!

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                            self.selectSV.center.y = 288.0
                        })
```

Easy when you know how... much to learn in this domain...